# Rithmic apps not working correctly with wine

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, windows, wine

I installed the latest versions of R Trader Pro and R manager on my Ubuntu 22.04 but the apps aren’t working correctly. They are very slow and the feature of searching doesn’t work on them and they keep shutting down after a while.

Please help !

Comment: Check with `https://www.winehq.org`. Not all Windows programs are available through `wine`. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a `wine` problem.